# Removing a "package" via DISM in a Windows 8 from recovery options (cant boot after update)

Tags: windows-8, boot, updates, dism

today i insatlled about 700mb of updates for my Windows 8 x64 (had not updated it since Jan2014). after update, when it asked to restart, i restarted and then it never booted up again! just a blank screen and a mouse cursor. 
I cant even go to Safe Mode and dont have a restore point (had disabled it before). so i have to uninstall updates via CMD in recovery options of Windows 8 DVD.

when i use `dism /image:C:\ /get-packages` to get package names, it says:

> Error: 87
>
> The /image option that is specified points to a running
>   windows installation, to service the running operating system, use the
>   /online option. for more inforamtion refer to the help by running
>   dism.exe /online /?

but when i run `dism.exe /online /?` it says:

> Error: 50
>
> dism does not support servicing Windows PE with the /online option.
>   the dism log file can be found at x:windows\dism\dism.log

Please help me what i am doing wrong? and as i dont know which update caused windows to not to boot up, should i remove all the installed packages?
i it is required to put the dism.log here, please tell how can i copy it to usb flash via cmd.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I ve gone further, found out i should use H instead of C to get packages list. then i exported packages list to a txt file and created a batch file to remove all the updates automatically. the batch is something like this:

> dism /image:h:\ /remove-package /PackageName:Package_for_KB2871997~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.2.6.2
>
> dism /image:h:\ /remove-package /PackageName:Package_for_KB2894851~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.2.1.2
>
> dism /image:h:\ /remove-package /PackageName:Package_for_KB2894855~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.2.2.0
>
> . . .

it is 70 sentences, and these 70 updates are only the latest updates which caused this boot problem. but the problem starts after successfully unistalling only the first 11 updates, for the remaining 59 updates this error occures:

> Package_for_KB2995387: The specified image is no longer serviceable and may be corrupted.
>
> Discard the modified image and start again.
>
> Error: 0x800f0830

what should i do?

Comment: Reinstall Windows, obviously. Also, update regularly.

Comment: Reinstalling Win 8 results in External Apps loss. i want to fix the current Windows...